# A correct python regexp returns NoneType

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to get some substrings from text.

Using https://pythex.org/ to check my regular expression

pythex.org shows that it's everything correct with my regexp, but when I try to use it into my code second regexp doesn't work and **re** returns

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

I want to print uri variable. Only timestamp is returned. Example of code:

```
import re
line = "2019-01-30 01:05:26.255595500 tracker uri='/tracker_log/?f=__lxGc__&step=1&ses_id=2yz65vcsg0k8zk1952295510&id=123123&type=ad&rt=952301228' referer='https://instagram.com' ua='Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0'"

timestamp = re.match("\d+-\d+-\d+.\d+:.\d+:.\d+.\d+", line)
if timestamp:
    print(timestamp.group(0))
uri = re.match("(?<=uri=\').+(?=\' ref)", line)
if uri:
    print(uri.group(0))
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [I can't reproduce your problem](https://rextester.com/RVNXL85148), and your code is working for me.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the OP is expecting 2 things to be output (datetime and uri), not 1. If you change `re.match` to `re.search`, as @benvc correctly suggests, then the OP's issue is resolved.

Comment: You could just avoid regex altogether, you know as the saying goes: _Some people, when confronted with a problem, think“I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems._ 
For example, 
`uri_str = next(filter(  lambda str : str.startswith('uri'), line.split(' ') ))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`re.match` only returns a match object if the beginning of the string matches the regex pattern, which is why you are successfully matching the timestamp at the beginning of the string but not matching the uri string.

Use `re.search` instead to return a match object for the first location in the string where the regex pattern matches.

For example:

```
import re

line = "2019-01-30 01:05:26.255595500 tracker uri='/tracker_log/?f=__lxGc__&step=1&ses_id=2yz65vcsg0k8zk1952295510&id=123123&type=ad&rt=952301228' referer='https://instagram.com' ua='Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0'"

uri = re.search(r"(?<=uri=\').+(?=\' ref)", line)

print(uri.group(0))
# OUTPUT
# /tracker_log/?f=__lxGc__&step=1&ses_id=2yz65vcsg0k8zk1952295510&id=123123&type=ad&rt=952301228
```